# ReferenceError: sorted is not defined and other errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, validation, mongoose

I am trying to implement a login system: the sorted array contains pairs of firstnames and passwords, which need to get checked (this is already implemented). My Postman request does contain firstname, eMail and password. But apparently I get a load of errors.
I have the following code:

```
var express = require('express');
const app = express();
const User = require('./models/user.js');
var _ = require('lodash');
User.find({},{ firstname: 1, password: 1 }, async function(err, users) {
  const flattenUsers = _(users).map(({firstname, password}) => ([firstname, password])).flatten().value();
  console.log(flattenUsers);
  const sorted = await flattenUsers.reduce((a, e, i) => (i % 2 || a.push([]), a[a.length - 1].push(e), a), []);
app.post('/api/login', async function (req, res){
  try  {
    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10);
    console.log("Hashed pw: ", hashedPassword);
    console.log(await bcrypt.compare('testtest',hashedPassword));
    var user = new User({ loginId: req.body.id, firstname: req.body.username, password: hashedPassword });
    sorted.forEach(([email, password]) => {
      bcrypt.compare(password, users[email]).then((e, r) => {
        // r = true if hash = hashed pw
        console.log("Yeet");
      })
    })
    jwt2.sign({user}, 'secrethere', { expiresIn: '15min'}, (err, token) =>{
    res.json({
      token
    });
  });
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).send()
    console.log(err);
  }

});
});
```

I get the following errors:

```
ReferenceError: sorted is not defined
    at C:\Users\User\Documents\Carina\Canopus\src\app.js:224:5
Error [ValidationError]: User validation failed: eMail: Path `eMail` is required., firstname: Path `firstname` is required.
    at ValidationError.inspect (C:\Users\User\Documents\Carina\Canopus\node_modules\mongoose\lib\error\validation.js:61:24)
    at formatValue (internal/util/inspect.js:563:31)
    at inspect (internal/util/inspect.js:221:10)
    at formatWithOptions (internal/util/inspect.js:1693:40)
    at Object.Console.<computed> (internal/console/constructor.js:277:10)
    at Object.warn (internal/console/constructor.js:287:61)
    at C:\Users\User\Documents\Carina\Canopus\src\app.js:220:31
    at C:\Users\User\Documents\Carina\Canopus\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4599:16       
    at C:\Users\User\Documents\Carina\Canopus\node_modules\mongoose\lib\utils.js:256:11        
    at C:\Users\User\Documents\Carina\Canopus\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:468:16        
    at C:\Users\User\Documents\Carina\Canopus\node_modules\kareem\index.js:246:48
    at next (C:\Users\User\Documents\Carina\Canopus\node_modules\kareem\index.js:167:27)       
    at next (C:\Users\User\Documents\Carina\Canopus\node_modules\kareem\index.js:169:9)        
    at Kareem.execPost (C:\Users\User\Documents\Carina\Canopus\node_modules\kareem\index.js:217:3)
    at _handleWrapError (C:\Users\User\Documents\Carina\Canopus\node_modules\kareem\index.js:245:21)
    at C:\Users\User\Documents\Carina\Canopus\node_modules\kareem\index.js:272:14 {
  errors: {
    eMail: MongooseError [ValidatorError]: Path `eMail` is required.
        at new ValidatorError (C:\Users\User\Documents\Carina\Canopus\node_modules\mongoose\lib\error\validator.js:29:11)
        at validate (C:\Users\User\Documents\Carina\Canopus\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1055:13)
        at C:\Users\User\Documents\Carina\Canopus\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1109:11
        at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
        at SchemaString.SchemaType.doValidate (C:\Users\User\Documents\Carina\Canopus\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1064:14)
        at C:\Users\User\Documents\Carina\Canopus\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:2236:9 
        at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:75:11) {
      message: 'Path `eMail` is required.',
      name: 'ValidatorError',
      properties: [Object],
      kind: 'required',
      path: 'eMail',
      value: undefined,
      reason: undefined,
      [Symbol(mongoose:validatorError)]: true
    },
    firstname: MongooseError [ValidatorError]: Path `firstname` is required.
        at new ValidatorError (C:\Users\User\Documents\Carina\Canopus\node_modules\mongoose\lib\error\validator.js:29:11)
        at validate (C:\Users\User\Documents\Carina\Canopus\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1055:13)
        at C:\Users\User\Documents\Carina\Canopus\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1109:11
        at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
        at SchemaString.SchemaType.doValidate (C:\Users\User\Documents\Carina\Canopus\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1064:14)
        at C:\Users\User\Documents\Carina\Canopus\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:2236:9 
        at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:75:11) {
      message: 'Path `firstname` is required.',
      name: 'ValidatorError',
      properties: [Object],
      kind: 'required',
      path: 'firstname',
      value: undefined,
      reason: undefined,
      [Symbol(mongoose:validatorError)]: true
    }
  },
  _message: 'User validation failed',
  name: 'ValidationError'
}
```

My user.js:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({

    firstname: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    lastname: String,
    eMail: { 
    type: String, 
    required: true,
    unique: true 
    }, 
    password: String,
    active: Boolean

});

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
```

Comment: declare `const sorted = []` at top of the file.

Comment: @SaurabhAgrawal thanks, that fixed my ReferenceError but the other errors remain.

Comment: It's a validation error from Mongoose. According to your schema, `firstname` and `eMail` are required attributes so when you create a user in the line `var user = new User({...})`, you need to pass all the required attributes and they must be of correct type.

Comment: @AjayDabas This `var user = new User({ loginId: req.body.id, firstname: {req.body.username, required:true},eMail: {req.body.eMail, required:true}, password: hashedPassword });` doesn't work, how do I do it correctly?

Comment: There's no `loginId` field defined in your User schema. Why are you using it? You have to include it first in the schema or maybe by `loginId`, you actually mean email ID in which case you have to use `eMail` in place of `loginId`.

Comment: @AjayDabas I renamed it. I still get `SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'` :/

Comment: Try `var user = new User({firstname: req.body.username,eMail: req.body.eMail, password: hashedPassword });`

Comment: @AjayDabas I get `Error [ValidationError]: User validation failed: firstname: Path `firstname` is required.` and the same other errors

Comment: Do `console.log(req.body.username,req.body.eMail)` before that. Check if these are indeed valid strings. I guess they're null or undefined.

Comment: I fixed it to req.body.firstname (there is no username, my bad). Now I don't get yeet printed out even if I put in the correct login data

Comment: @AjayDabas And it also gives me the token (response) back regardless whether the login is ok or not...

Comment: This is all because of promises. You're sending the response before the promise containing `yeet` printing code is resolved and hence it's not printed in the console. You have to chain your promises in proper order.

Comment: @AjayDabas How do I do that?

Comment: I just figured out that my sorted array is empty before the `sorted.forEach` part. Is it because of promises again and how do I fix this?

Comment: I don't think that's because of promises. Recheck your logic of creating `sorted` array to make sure that it won't return an empty array.

Comment: @AjayDabas the `await console.log` in the upper part of code is working but if I add it to the `app.post('/api/login...` scope it prints out nothing :/

Comment: As I told you, it's because of promises. It's not an error, it's just your promises are not aligned properly. I cannot figure out the correct order here until I reproduce this myself. If you have your code open-sourced on GitHub or somewhere, share the link here.

Comment: @AjayDabas apparently the rest of the code is closed source. The provided code should be enough to reproduce the problem, if more code is needed let me know. I can't seem to find any information about promises alignment online..